# Websocket: set manual id for client at connection

Tags: c#, node.js, xamarin, websocket, chat

I want to realize a chat one to one with websocket. 
My client is a Xamarin Forms app (Android, iOs, Uwp) and backend is Nodejs.

- I can't use Socket.io because there's no well working nuget
- I can't use Xmpp protocol because there's no well working/update nuget
- I can't use Mqtt because is one to many  protocoll (I use it for group chat)

I use this https://github.com/websockets/ws on Node but I can't find a way to set a mine clientId (email for eg.) that can help me to send message to a specific client.
There's any way to do this?